# How to hide modal scroll bar

Tags: css

I want to set the modal class to be height 750px even if the screen shrink. I was able to set content1 to overflow in the modal but `.modal` takes the whole screen.

```js
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65815926/edit#
```

```css
.content1 {
  overflow-y:auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="content1">
      </div>
      <div class="content2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a modal that I want to set height 750px in this modal but when I open the chrome dev tool it will create a scroll bar on the right side. I tried `overflow: hidden` but this won't let me scroll the popup. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap, you can always try:

```
.modal-open .modal {
margin-right: -10px;
margin-left: -10px;
}
```

A tad bit hacky but it will visually hide the scrollbar, still enabling the ability to scroll.

Updated answer:

You can try hiding the scrollbars with CSS:

```
.modal-open .modal::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but the modal becomes off-center. I want to centralize the modal.

Comment: How about hiding the scrollbars with css? See updated answer.